# Ударение в выражении «сложить с иксом»

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно поставить ударение: "сложить с Иксом" или "сложить с иксОм" (в смысле икс – переменная)
и почему?

Answer (score 2):

В словаре Зарвы - **И**ксом, хотя в профессиональном жаргоне повсеместно - икс**о**м.

Логика-то некоторая есть. В иноязычных словах ударение редко бывает подвижным. А в названиях букв вообще не припомню. Другое дело, что это статистика, т.е. логика наблюдения, а не причинно-следственная, на вопрос почему она ответа не даёт.

Answer (score 0):

С **И**ксом. Почему?  Стул -стУлом, стол - столОм. Логики нет. Традиция.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы чаше слышала Икс**о**м. Но "з**е**том". Объяснить трудно. Возможно, сказывается парадигма слов типа "фикса". КС - в русском нехарактерное сочетание звуков (в греческом, если не ошибаюсь, считается одним звуком), и его хочется разнести по разным слогам, а это проще получается с ударением на флексии.

Answer (score 0):

"Сложить с и'ксом" - это и более привычно, и правильно (в соответствии с вариантами, указанными в словарях). Вариант "с иксо'м" - разговорный, его употребляют в основном профессионалы (математики, физики и иже с ними), да и то, безусловно, не все.